# ¿Cómo puedo recibir un conjunto de arreglo de un formulario a un controlador asp.net core mvc ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una tabla con varias filas que lo agrupa un formulario con varios `inputs` y `select` que son arreglo, ejemplo solo voy a colocar los `input`:

```
<form id="frmMaterial" method="POST">
<input name="material[]"/> 
<input name="material[]"/> 
<input name="material[]"/> 
</form>
```

he intentado enviar todo el arreglo de elementos que contiene ese formulario pero en mi controlador no me lo recibe, este es código de `ajax`

```
$("#btnEditar").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "editar",
        data: $("#frmMaterial").serialize(),
        success: function (respuesta) {
            if (respuesta[0].code === "1") {
                table.ajax.reload(null, false);
                toastr.success(respuesta[0].description);
            } else {
                toastr.error(respuesta[0].description);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Este es parte del controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<List<IdentityError>> editar(List<DPAct> actividad)
{
   int cantExito = 0;
    int cantError = 0;
    code = "0";
   try
   {
     List<DPAct> lista = actividad;
```

pero en la variable actividad no recibo nada, cómo puedo hacer para recibir esos arreglos que tengo en ese formulario? Estoy utilizando `asp.net core 2.2`

Comment: has un `console.log($("#frmMaterial").serialize())` y te daras cuenta si es la misma estructura que esperas en el controlador editar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el enlace de datos (data binding) de tu método de acción. Intenta con:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<string> material)
{ ...
```